# sending images from client to server using socket python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-services, client

I'm trying to send multiple images from client to server .
from my client I send one  image at a time then for each image I get the size in the server and then send the size back to client and then try and store all the sizes of all images in a table .
I wrote this code and it doesn't seem to work:

client.py:

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
import sys
import pickle
import socket 
import os
import numpy

reload(sys)

def readFileImages(strFolderName):
    st = os.path.join(strFolderName, "*.png")
    print st
    return glob.glob(st)



client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
client_socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 4000))

list1=readFileImages("test")
myoutput =[]
while (list1):
  for im in list1:

     f=open(im,"rb")

     while True:

          veri = f.read()

          if not veri:

                break

          client_socket.send(veri)


     f.close()

  data = client_socket.recv(4096)
  data_arr=pickle.loads(data)

  newrow=numpy.asarray(data_arr)
  myoutput=numpy.vstack([myoutput,newrow])

client_socket.close()



numpy.savetxt("testTable.csv",myoutput,delimiter=",")
```

server.py:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
s.bind(("127.0.0.1",4000))
s.listen(5)

client_socket, address = s.accept()

print "Connected to - ",address,"\n"



fname="test.png"

fp = open(fname,'wb')

 # image
 while True:
    strng = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not strng:
        break
    fp.write(strng)

 fp.close()



 #T[0]=detect_carte_grise(fp)
 im = Image.open(fp)

 T= im.size #width,height
 data=pickle.dumps(T)
 client_socket.send(data)
```

and why do i get this error ?:[errno98] address already in use
I cannot even connect to server

Comment: TCP is a stream. You need some kind of protocol for multiple file transfer. Best, use a some existing one, e.g. HTTP.

Comment: what if try socket.sendall would that work without the protocol?

Comment: No. You need a protocol. Use some already to use HTTP-Server, or look at their source code.

Comment: You can read the image 1024 bytes at a time and send it in order. The server can receive each 1024 byte "chunk" and can recreate the image file.

Answer (score 1):

First, in server code you bind to port, but in client code, you need to CONNECT to that server. You are binding in both of your scripts and address is already used by the first running script. so in client drop bind and change to `client_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4000))`. That will resolve current issues, if you have any more, please, ask another question.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error, I Changed the "port number". It's worked fine